# Can I log MS Insights calls in a separate thread?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have console app and i use Microsoft insights, but sending an event or exception is slow so I want send insights on different thread.

```
let worker = new Worker(__dirname + '/insights.js');
worker.on('message', (msg) => { 
                console.log("First value is: ", msg);

//in worker
let a = 10000000000;
while(a > 1){
    a--;
}
parentPort.postMessage(a);
```

I try use worker thread but it's does not help me. They work synchronously.
For example I create new worker and run loop there

Can I somehow send event into insights in parallel and continue running other code in the mean time?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I made a few small syntax and grammar fixes to make the question a bit easier to read and find. I hope you find your answer soon!

Comment: Can you post the code that you are trying to run while the worker is running as well as how you are using the App Insights SDK to send events? Sending data shouldn't be having a significant impact on performance, and using a worker would drastically increase the complexity of sending telemetry accurately so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: child process helped... but not fully

Answer (score 0):

I change code in index.js  and now i use the following:

```
function sendLog(functionName, obj , commandName = ''){     
    const cp = require('child_process');
    const subprocess = cp.fork( __dirname + '/insights.js', [], {
        detached: true,
        stdio: [ 'ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore', 'ipc' ]
      });
    subprocess.send({function:functionName, obj: obj, commandName: commandName, UUID : uuid, scriptName: roundCommand});
    subprocess.unref();
}
```

In insights.js i trackEvent. It's work fine, i can send logs in background. 
But when in my index.js i execute command whitch run for example App C# console app in whict i againe execute index.js file creating new process:

```
var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = $"/C {PathToCommand} {command} {arguments}",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
```

the main process will freez... i don't now why, i detach all child processes .... maybe something in how new process execute from C# application and as result child proccess can't detached from parent.... i don't now...